# Background in shading mode is always black

Tags: shaders

[image]In shading mode the background behind my object is always black. Why is this happening? is it because my pc spec is low or what? my pc spec is core-i5, 6 GB ram with built in graphics card intel hd 4600.

Comment: does it happen with all the files you open or is it just for this one? What are your Viewport Shading settings?

Comment: it happens for all the files.